# "View Current Requests" in IIS 8.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8, worker-process

ASP .NET application is deployed on IIS 8.0 and is using DefaultAppPool. I enabled the Request Monitoring from the server manager and "View Current Requests" Option is appearing for the working process, but clicking on that  is not showing up anything. Although, the requests to the application are flowing continuously.

I've tried disabling Logging and adding RequestMonitorModule at the host level but with no success.

Here is the snapshot of IIS Server:
[image: Here is the snapshot of IIS Server:]